# Image Positioning at the right corner in jquery mobile

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm working on mobile app. I'm trying to align 3 images one below the other at the right corner with adjacent to the text. Please suggest me. Thanks in advance. Below is my Code

```
  <div>
 <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-input="#filterBasic-input" data-icon="false">
  <li class="custom">
   <h3>Week </h3>
   <p class="topic"><a href="#">Sun </a></p>
   <p><a href="#">Mon</a></p>
   <p><a href="#">Tue </a> </p>
    <p class="ui-li-aside"> <span><a href="#"> <img src="images/progressnew.png" alt="download">     </a></span> <span><a href="#"> <img src="images/progressnew.png" alt="download"> </a></span> <span><a   href="#"> <img src="images/progressnew.png" alt="download"> </a></span> </p>
   </li>
   </ul>
   </div>

  <styles>
  .ui-listview .ui-li-aside {
   position: absolute;
   top: 1em;
   right: 0.444em;
   margin:24px;
  text-align: right;
  }
  </styles>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add:

```
.ui-listview .ui-li-aside span{
       display: block;
}
```

This tells the SPANS that contain the images to display as block elements instead of inline elements.

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/aymgg86p/)**